# In fabric js using react the values of freedrawingBrush is changing but it is not showing up

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a drawing app in react with typescript and fabricJS and every other thing works I can draw normally but when I try to change the brush or color values they get changed in the canvas object but it doesn't show up.

here is the component:

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useFabricContext } from '../Context/FabricContext'
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
import { Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'



const Whiteboard = () => {

    const [width, setwidth] = useState<number>(window.innerWidth - 100)
    const [height, setheight] = useState<number>(window.innerHeight - 100)
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        setheight(window.innerHeight - 100)
        setwidth(window.innerWidth - 100)
    })
    const { FabricRef, canvas, setcanvas, color, setcolor, brush, setbrush } = useFabricContext()

    useEffect(() => {
         setcanvas(new fabric.Canvas(FabricRef?.current, {
            renderOnAddRemove: true,
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            isDrawingMode: true,
            height: height,
            width: width,
        }))
        console.log(brush, color);
        

    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = color;
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = brush;
            console.log(canvas.freeDrawingBrush)
        }
    }, [color, brush]);


    const handleColor = (color:string) => {
        setcolor(color)
    }
    const handleBrush = (brush:number) => {
        setbrush(brush)
    }

    return (
        <div className='p-2  bg-body-secondary d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>
            <Nav variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home">
            <NavDropdown title="Color" id="nav-color">
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="4.1" onClick={()=>{handleColor("#0D6EFD")}} className='bg-primary text-white'>Blue</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="4.2" onClick={()=>{handleColor("#DC3545")}} className='bg-danger text-white'>Red</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="4.3" onClick={()=>{handleColor("#FFC107")}} className='bg-warning text-white'>Orange</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="4.4" onClick={()=>{handleColor("#000")}} className='bg-black text-white'>Black</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="4.5" onClick={()=>{handleColor("#0DCAF0")}} className='bg-info text-white'>Cyan</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
                <NavDropdown title="Brush" id="nav-brush">
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="5.1" onClick={() => {handleBrush(5)}} ><div id='brush-1' className='bg-black w-100' ></div></NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider/>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="5.2" onClick={() => {handleBrush(10)}} ><div id='brush-2' className='bg-black w-100' ></div></NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider/>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="5.3" onClick={() => {handleBrush(15)}} ><div id='brush-3' className='bg-black w-100' ></div></NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider/>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="5.4" onClick={() => {handleBrush(20)}} ><div id='brush-4' className='bg-black w-100' ></div></NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider/>
                    <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="5.5" onClick={() => {handleBrush(25)}} ><div id='brush-5' className='bg-black w-100' ></div></NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <canvas id='mainCanvas' className='shadow' ref={FabricRef}></canvas>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Whiteboard
```

and here is the context I'm using:

```
import React, { ReactNode, createContext, useContext, useRef, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

interface FabricContextType {
  FabricRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement | null>;
  canvas: fabric.Canvas;
  setcanvas: Dispatch<SetStateAction<fabric.Canvas | null>>;
  brush: number;
  setbrush: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
  color: string;
  setcolor: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
}

const Canvas = createContext<FabricContextType | undefined>(undefined);

const FabricContext: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const FabricRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const [canvas, setcanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas | null>(null);
  const [brush, setbrush] = useState<number>(5);
  const [color, setcolor] = useState<string>('#000');

  const contextValue: FabricContextType = {
    FabricRef,
    canvas: canvas as fabric.Canvas, // Asserting non-null to avoid TypeScript errors
    setcanvas,
    brush,
    setbrush,
    color,
    setcolor,
  };

  return <Canvas.Provider value={contextValue}>
    {
      children
    }
  </Canvas.Provider>;
};

const useFabricContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(Canvas);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useFabricContext must be used within a FabricContext provider');
  }
  return context;
};

export { FabricContext, useFabricContext };
```

I've tried changing where I change the value like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setcanvas(new fabric.Canvas(FabricRef?.current, {
            renderOnAddRemove: true,
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            isDrawingMode: true,
            height: height,
            width: width,
        }))
        console.log(brush, color);
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = color;
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = brush;
        }


    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = color;
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = brush;
            console.log(canvas.freeDrawingBrush)
        }
    }, [canvas, color, brush]);
```

but, if I do this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const Canvas = new fabric.Canvas(FabricRef?.current, {
            renderOnAddRemove: true,
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            isDrawingMode: true,
            height: height,
            width: width,
        })
        console.log(brush, color);

        Canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = color;
        Canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = brush;



    }, [])
```

and change the initial value in the context only then the values take the initial value, but not the changed values after I change then
[image: this is the console log I see when I change the values]